# dijit/Dojo Context Menu Not Showing SubMenu

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

So basically im a newb when it comes to dojo only second day working with it but ive tried everything and cant seem to get this submenu to work, basically what i have is a context menu for my dgrid column head that works fine besides the fact that the submenu wont show, and the second problem i am having is the context menu wont open at the mouse but rather at the bottom of the webpage or application, any body have any ideas?

[here is a live version of the application](http://dautidevelopment.byethost7.com/)

```
var activeMenuItem; 

grid.on('.dgrid-column-goals:contextmenu', function(evt) {     
    evt.preventDefault(); 

}); 
require([
"dijit/Menu",
"dijit/MenuItem",
"dijit/CheckedMenuItem",
"dijit/MenuSeparator",
"dijit/PopupMenuItem",
"dojo/domReady!"
```

], function(Menu, MenuItem, CheckedMenuItem, MenuSeparator, PopupMenuItem){

```
 var menu = new Menu({ 
    targetNodeIds: [grid.domNode], 
    selector: ".dgrid-column-goals" 
}); 
menu.addChild(new MenuItem({   
    label: "Hide Column", 
    onClick: function() {grid.styleColumn("goals", "display: none;");} } 
));

var submenu = new Menu({

    label: "Alignment"

});

submenu.addChild(new MenuItem({   
    label: "Alignment-Right", 
    onClick: function() {grid.styleColumn("number", "text-align:right");} } 
));
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by adding following css incase anyone comes across the same problem.

```
.dijitPopup {
    position: absolute;
}
```